# Non-relativistic approximation of the retarded Lienard-Wiechert field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I'm working on a revision of the absorber theory of radiation proposed by Wheeler and Feynman on their paper "[Interaction with the Absorber as the Mechanism of Radiation](http://ayuba.fr/mach_effect/absorber_wheeler_feynman_.pdf)". On page 161 they say the retarded field of the source reduces to
\begin{equation}
-\left(\frac{e\mathfrak{U}}{r_k c^2}\right) \sin(\mathfrak{U},r_k)
\end{equation}
together with a term of electrostatic origin. My problem is that I don't completely understand where this terms comes from.

Using the Liénard-Wiechert potentials, I get that the field for a point charge with arbitrary motion is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} = e \left[\left(\frac{\hat{\mathbf{n}}-\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\gamma^2 R^2 (1-\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta})^3} \right) + \frac{1}{c} \frac{\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\left((\hat{\mathbf{n}}-\boldsymbol{\beta})\times\dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)}{R(1-\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta})^3 }  \right] 
\end{equation}

We're interested in the limit $\beta\ll 1$, so we are left with

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} = e \left[\frac{\hat{\mathbf{n}}}{\gamma^2 R^2 }  + \frac{1}{c} \frac{\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)}{R }  \right] =  \frac{e \hat{\mathbf{n}}}{\gamma^2 R^2 }  +  \frac{e\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\mathfrak{U}\right)}{R c^2}   
\end{equation}

Does this mean that $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\mathfrak{U}\right)$ is equal to $-\mathfrak{U}\sin(\mathfrak{U},r_k)$ or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-\hat n \times (\hat n \times \vec{\mathfrak{U}})$ is the component of $\vec{\mathfrak{U}}$ perpendicular to $\hat n$ and has a length $\mathfrak{U}\sin(\hat n \cdot \vec{\mathfrak{U}})$, so it appears they are just giving the value of this component.